# Plotting a time series with ggplot geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2, timeserieschart

I'm trying to plot multiple time series plots based on different datasets. The first data set plotted perfectly.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
data("economics")

economics %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, unemploy, pop)) + 
  geom_line(col = "maroon") + 
  xlab("Year") + 
  ylab("U.S. Unemployment Rate")
```

[image: Unemployment Plot]

The second data set may need some additional conditioning, but essentially it's showing the same type of data, but isn't plotting the same. The data can be found here https://fiscaldata.treasury.gov/datasets/debt-to-the-penny/debt-to-the-penny.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
data(debt)

debt <- read.csv("C:##path here to the data")

debt %>%
  filter(Calendar.Month.Number==12 & Calendar.Day.Number==31) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Calendar.Year, Debt.Held.by.the.Public)) +
  geom_line(col = "blue")
```

[image: Debt plot]

**What should I be doing differently?**

Comment: It looks like the x and y variables in `debt` were read into R as factors, rather than numbers. See what column types you have using `str(debt)`.

Comment: Looking at the CSV from the URL that you gave, I think the simplest solution is to use `read_csv` (from `readr`, part of tidyverse) instead of `read.csv`. The former reads the data with the correct column types for plotting (date and numeric).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know a way to convert chr to  date? That does seem to be the difference between the two.

Comment: Genius. That worked.

Comment: I gave more details in the answer below. Please vote for/accept it if it helped solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `read.csv` reads the column `Record.Date` as type character, by default. `ggplot` then interprets the date variable as a factor, whereas you wanted a date type on the x-axis.

You can solve this in a few ways.

1. Use `readr::read_csv`. In this case the column will be read as type date because it's in a standard "Year-Month-Day" format, but that isn't always the case.
2. Specify the column type using the `colClasses` argument.

   ```
   debt <- read.csv("DebtPenny_20160909_20210909.csv", colClasses = c("Record.Date" = "Date"))
   ```
3. Convert to type date after reading the data.

   ```
   debt$Record.Date <- as.Date(debt$Record.Date)
   ```